# Zip directory without header

Tags: go

I use the following code to zip directory , the problem is that I want to zip the dir content without the header e.g. , I try to play with the basedir without success

```
dir1
 -file1
 -file2
   -file10
```

when I unzip I need to get only

```
-file1
 -file2
   -file10
```

This is the code

```
func Zip(params ...string) error {
        zipfile, err := os.Create(params[1])
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        defer zipfile.Close()

        archive := zip.NewWriter(zipfile)
        defer archive.Close()

        info, err := os.Stat(params[0])
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        var baseDir string
        if info.IsDir(); len(params) > 2 {
            baseDir = params[2]
        } else {
            baseDir = filepath.Base(params[0])
        }

        if baseDir != "" {
            baseDir += "/"
        }

        filepath.Walk(params[0], func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }

            if info.IsDir() {
                return nil
            }

            header, err := zip.FileInfoHeader(info)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }

            if baseDir != "" {
                header.Name = filepath.Join(strings.TrimPrefix(path, baseDir))
            }

            header.Method = zip.Deflate

            writer, err := archive.CreateHeader(header)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }

            file, err := os.Open(path)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            defer file.Close()
            _, err = io.Copy(writer, file)
            return err
        })

        return err
    }
```

And I use it

```
Zip("../dir1","../"+zipname+".zip","dir1")
```

The problem that it zip's also the dir name...How can I do that ?

Comment: @Marc - the code is diffrent ...

Comment: The function call is different, everything else is exactly the same. If you understand your code, the linked answer tells you all you need. If you don't, please take the time to understand it.

Comment: @Marc - the code `header.Name = strings.TrimPrefix(path, source)` is used and still the basedir is zipped

Comment: That's because `basedir` is set to `params2` which is `dir`. I believe `Walk` passes `../dir1`, so it won't trim anything. trace your code, add debug statements, and find which arguments to pass.

Comment: @Marc - even if I remove params2 its not working becouse the source is `"../dir1" `, any suggestion

Comment: Pass `../dir1/` as your `params[2]`. But really, add print statements to understand what the code does.

Comment: @Marc - Thanks for the tip it works!  when I use this logic from my main program it works because providing path like `"../dir1"` is simple from the main program, but now I need to call to the zip func deeper in the program,  and im providing the full path to it like `os.Getwd()` + "dirname"`, any idea?